# AWK: add a sequential number out of 4 digits

Tags: awk, sed, bioinformatics, fasta, tr

How do I achieve from following `string.ext`

```
>Lipoprotein releasing system transmembrane protein LolC
MKWLWFAYQNVIRNRRRSLMTILIIAVGTAAILLSNGFALYTYDNLREGSALASGHVIIAHVDHFDKEEEIPMEYGLSDYEDIERHIAADDRVRMAIPRLQFSGLISNGDKSVIFMGTGVDPEGEFDIGGVLTNVLTGNTLSTHSAPDAVPEVMLAKDLAKQLHADIGGLLTLLATTADGALNALDVQVRGIFSTGVPEMDKRMLAVALPTAQELIMTDKVGTLSVYLHEIEQTDAMWAVLAEWYPNFATQPWWEQASFYFKVRALYDIIFGVMGVIILLIVFFTITNTLSMTIVERTRETGTLLALGTLPRQIMRNFALEALLIGLAGALLGMLIAGFTSITLFIAEIQMPPPPGSTEGYPLYIYFSPWLYGITSLLVVTLSIAAAFLTSRKAARKPIVEALAHV
>Phosphoserine phosphatase (EC 3.1.3.3)
MFQEHALTLAIFDLDNTLLAGDSDFLWGVFLVERGIVDGDEFERENERFYRAYQEGDLDIFEFLRFAFRPLRDNRLEDLKRWRQDFLREKIEPAILPMACELVEHHRAAGDTLLIITSTNEFVTAPIAEQLGIPNLIATVPEQLHGCYTGEAAGTPAFQAGKVKRLLDWLEETSTELAGSTFYSDSHNDIPLLEWVDHPVATDPDDRLRGYARDRGWPIISLREEIAP
```

**to change the sequential number after `string` to a 4 digit number (starting with `0001`) and separate that number with `|` from `string`**, so that `output` is returned like:

```
>string|0001|Lipoprotein_releasing_system_transmembrane_protein_LolC
MKWLWFAYQNVIRNRRRSLMTILIIAVGTAAILLSNGFALYTYDNLREGSALASGHVIIAHVDHFDKEEEIPMEYGLSDYEDIERHIAADDRVRMAIPRLQFSGLISNGDKSVIFMGTGVDPEGEFDIGGVLTNVLTGNTLSTHSAPDAVPEVMLAKDLAKQLHADIGGLLTLLATTADGALNALDVQVRGIFSTGVPEMDKRMLAVALPTAQELIMTDKVGTLSVYLHEIEQTDAMWAVLAEWYPNFATQPWWEQASFYFKVRALYDIIFGVMGVIILLIVFFTITNTLSMTIVERTRETGTLLALGTLPRQIMRNFALEALLIGLAGALLGMLIAGFTSITLFIAEIQMPPPPGSTEGYPLYIYFSPWLYGITSLLVVTLSIAAAFLTSRKAARKPIVEALAHV
>string|0002|Phosphoserine_phosphatase_(EC_3_1_3_3)
MFQEHALTLAIFDLDNTLLAGDSDFLWGVFLVERGIVDGDEFERENERFYRAYQEGDLDIFEFLRFAFRPLRDNRLEDLKRWRQDFLREKIEPAILPMACELVEHHRAAGDTLLIITSTNEFVTAPIAEQLGIPNLIATVPEQLHGCYTGEAAGTPAFQAGKVKRLLDWLEETSTELAGSTFYSDSHNDIPLLEWVDHPVATDPDDRLRGYARDRGWPIISLREEIAP
```

the commands I came up until here are (`$faa` is referring to the filename `string.ext`)

```
faa=$1
var=$(basename "$faa" .ext)

awk '!/^>/ { printf "%s", $0; n = "\n" } /^>/ { print n $0; n = "" } END { printf "%s", n }' $faa >$faa.tmp
sed 's/ /_/g' $faa.tmp >$faa.tmp2
awk -v var="$var" '/>/{sub(">","&"var"|");sub(/\.ext/,x)}1' $faa.tmp2 >$faa.tmp3
awk '/>/{sub(/\|/,++i"|")}1' $faa.tmp3 >$faa.tmp4
tr '\.' '_' <$faa.tmp4 | tr '\:' '_' | sed 's/__/_/g' >$faa.tmp5
```

**Edit: I also want to change following characters to 1 underscore: `/` `.` `:`**

Comment: @ed-morton it is the basename, so `string` of the file `string.ext`

Comment: @tobi that got lost in the mind->site translation process - you should update your question to state that and to discuss the criteria for changing some characters to underscores (which some of us are guessing at right now from your small sample)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk '
    FNR==1 {base=FILENAME; sub(/\.[^.]+$/,"",base) }
    sub(/^>/,"") { gsub(/[\/ .:]+/,"_"); $0=sprintf(">%s|%04d|%s",base,++c,$0) }
1' string.ext
>string|0001|Lipoprotein_releasing_system_transmembrane_protein_LolC
MKWLWFAYQNVIRNRRRSLMTILIIAVGTAAILLSNGFALYTYDNLREGSALASGHVIIAHVDHFDKEEEIPMEYGLSDYEDIERHIAADDRVRMAIPRLQFSGLISNGDKSVIFMGTGVDPEGEFDIGGVLTNVLTGNTLSTHSAPDAVPEVMLAKDLAKQLHADIGGLLTLLATTADGALNALDVQVRGIFSTGVPEMDKRMLAVALPTAQELIMTDKVGTLSVYLHEIEQTDAMWAVLAEWYPNFATQPWWEQASFYFKVRALYDIIFGVMGVIILLIVFFTITNTLSMTIVERTRETGTLLALGTLPRQIMRNFALEALLIGLAGALLGMLIAGFTSITLFIAEIQMPPPPGSTEGYPLYIYFSPWLYGITSLLVVTLSIAAAFLTSRKAARKPIVEALAHV
>string|0002|Phosphoserine_phosphatase_(EC_3_1_3_3)
MFQEHALTLAIFDLDNTLLAGDSDFLWGVFLVERGIVDGDEFERENERFYRAYQEGDLDIFEFLRFAFRPLRDNRLEDLKRWRQDFLREKIEPAILPMACELVEHHRAAGDTLLIITSTNEFVTAPIAEQLGIPNLIATVPEQLHGCYTGEAAGTPAFQAGKVKRLLDWLEETSTELAGSTFYSDSHNDIPLLEWVDHPVATDPDDRLRGYARDRGWPIISLREEIAP
```

I'm assuming from your posted sample and code that you actually want every contiguous sequence of any combination of spaces, periods, forward slashes and/or colons converted to a single underscore.

Comment: now I came across a problem: my file contains the following: `>Alvin_0063|ID:9263708|phbA| Acetyl-CoA acetyltransferase [Allochromatium vinosum DSM 180]
MNENIVIVDAGRSAIGTFSGSLSSLSATEIGTAVLKGLLARTGLAPE` so the third `|` is problematic here, how do I fix that?

Comment: Post a new question with it's own [mcve] that includes that input and the associated expected output.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use perl here:

```
perl -pe '
    next unless /^>/;     # only transform the "header" lines
    s/[\h.]/_/g;          # change dots and horizontal whitespace
    substr($_,1,0) = sprintf("string|%04d|", ++$n)  # insert the counter
' file
```

Comment: how do I exchange the `string` to a variable, that inserts the filename without extension? e.g. if my file is  `myfile.txt`, perl puts `myfile` instead of `string`?

Comment: In a perl `-p` loop, `$ARGV` holds the current filename, so use `sprintf("%s|%04d|", substr($ARGV,0,-4), ++$n)` assuming each extension is the last 4 chars of the filename.

Answer (score 1):

In awk.

```
$ awk '/^>/{n=sprintf("%04d",++i);sub(/^>/,">string|" n "|")}1' file
>string|0001|Lipoprotein releasing system transmembrane protein LolC
MKWLWFAYQNVIRNRRRSLMTILIIAVGTAAILLSNGFALYTYDNLREGSALASGHVIIAHVDHFDKEEEIPMEYGLSDYEDIERHIAADDRVRMAIPRLQFSGLISNGDKSVIFMGTGVDPEGEFDIGGVLTNVLTGNTLSTHSAPDAVPEVMLAKDLAKQLHADIGGLLTLLATTADGALNALDVQVRGIFSTGVPEMDKRMLAVALPTAQELIMTDKVGTLSVYLHEIEQTDAMWAVLAEWYPNFATQPWWEQASFYFKVRALYDIIFGVMGVIILLIVFFTITNTLSMTIVERTRETGTLLALGTLPRQIMRNFALEALLIGLAGALLGMLIAGFTSITLFIAEIQMPPPPGSTEGYPLYIYFSPWLYGITSLLVVTLSIAAAFLTSRKAARKPIVEALAHV
>string|0002|Phosphoserine phosphatase (EC 3.1.3.3)
MFQEHALTLAIFDLDNTLLAGDSDFLWGVFLVERGIVDGDEFERENERFYRAYQEGDLDIFEFLRFAFRPLRDNRLEDLKRWRQDFLREKIEPAILPMACELVEHHRAAGDTLLIITSTNEFVTAPIAEQLGIPNLIATVPEQLHGCYTGEAAGTPAFQAGKVKRLLDWLEETSTELAGSTFYSDSHNDIPLLEWVDHPVATDPDDRLRGYARDRGWPIISLREEIAP
```

Explained:

```
$ awk '
/^>/ {                          # if string starts with >
    n=sprintf("%04d",++i)       # iterate i from 1 and zeropad
    sub(/^>/,">string|" n "|")  # replace the > with stuff
}1' file                        # implicit output
```

Don't include `&` in `string` (see comments).

Comment: The only problem with that is that it'd fail if `string` contained backreferences (e.g. `&`). Best to avoid any flavor of `*sub()` when you're trying to use literal strings. Also note the expected output replaces spaces and periods with underscores.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F'[ \.]' 'BEGIN{a=1;OFS="_"}/^>/{$1=sprintf(">String|%04d",a);++a;print $0; next;}{print $0}' filename
```